# Knockout component viewmodel not defined when using AMD

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, requirejs, components

I've been trying to use Knockout components with require.js for a project I've been working on.  When I use the component it will display the HTML template, however the bindings within the template throw a reference error saying the field is undefined.
I believe this is because  1. The viewModel is undefined, or 2. The viewModel is not bound to the template. However I cannot figure out how to fix it.

I am using the built-in server in phpStorm with Firefox developer edition

index.php

```
<?php
    namespace project;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Project | Admin</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css"/>

    <style>
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <admin-header params=""></admin-header>

    <script src="js/vendor/require.js" data-main="js/app"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
    requirejs.config({
    paths: {

        jquery: 'vendor/jquery',

        postbox: 'vendor/knockout-postbox',
        domReady: 'vendor/domReady',
        text: 'vendor/text',
        knockout: 'vendor/knockout',

        hashchange: 'vendor/hashchange',
        underscore: 'vendor/underscore',

        ComponentManager: 'components/ComponentManager'
    },

    shim: {
        knockout: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        hashchange: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        underscore:{
            exports: '-'
        }
    }
});



require(['knockout', 'AdminViewModel', 'domReady!'], function(ko, AdminViewModel){
    ko.applyBindings(new AdminViewModel());
});
```

AdminViewModel.js

```
 define(['knockout', 'postbox', 'ComponentManager'], function( ko, postbox,  ComponentManager) {
    return function AdminViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.pageTitle = ko.observable('Home').publishOn('pageTitle');

        var componentManager = new ComponentManager();
        componentManager.registerComponents(['admin-header']);

        /*
        // doesnt work when registered in the parent view either

        ko.components.register(
            'admin-header', {
                require: 'components/admin-header/admin-header'
            }
        );
        */

    }
});
```

ComponentManager,js

```
define(['knockout', 'underscore', 'require'], function(ko, _, require){
    return function ComponentManager() {
        this.registerComponents = function(components) {

            _.each(components, function (component) {
                var componentPath = 'components/' + component + '/' + component;

                console.log("registering: " + componentPath );
                ko.components.register(component, {
                    require:  componentPath
                });
            });

        }
    }
});
```

admin-header.js
define(['knockout', 'postbox', 'text!./admin-header_template.html'],

```
function(ko, postbox, template){

   function AdminHeaderModel(params){
        var self = this;

        self.pageTitle = ko.observable('Title');//.subscripeTo('pageTitle', true, function(title){return title.toUpperCase()});
   }


    return {
        viewmodel: AdminHeaderModel,
        template: template
    };

});
```

admin-header-template.html

```
<div>
<h1>Project</h1>
<h1 data-bind="text: pageTitle"></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `admin-header` component code, you need to return a `viewModel` property rather than `viewmodel`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't even realize that mistake.  The components are working great now.